# Script that prevents the software to run unless other associate software is already running

Tags: scripts, autostart

I have a situation here. We wanted to prevent a software to run successfully unless the other software is already running. If the script has been run, it run the main software and it will check if the other software is already running and prompt a message or will automatically run that other software.

(EDITED)
Example:

1. Run the script
2. Check if the other software is already running; and
3. Check if the network is reachable.
4. If true, the main software should be able to run
5. Else if the network is unreachable,
6. Display error message that the network is down and need attention.

Is this possible on Ubuntu 11.04 and kindly provide the script?

Answer (score 0):

this script might work with some tweakings with your need

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
id_of_software=$(pidof <software name>)
if [[ -n $id_of_software ]]
    then
    echo "it is running" + $id_of_software
    run your script
else
    echo "not running"
    do something
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you explain by line that command? is it possible to add the check for the networking? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, kindly check this, Thanks.

#!/bin/bash

id_of_software=$(pidof OtherSoftware)
if [[ -n $id_of_software ]] then
    echo "Running" + $id_of_software
 BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
 LIBS="$(dirname $0)/../LIB"
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBS:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 cd $BASEDIR
 exec ./MainSoftware
else
    echo "not running"
 BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
 LIBS="$(dirname $0)/LIB"
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBS:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 cd $BASEDIR
 exec ./OtherSoftware

 BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
 LIBS="$(dirname $0)/../LIB"
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBS:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 cd $BASEDIR
 exec ./MainSoftware
fi